# Python script keeps outputting 2 elements to file

Tags: python, pandas, scipy, differential-equations, odeint

I'm attempting to integrate the zombie apocalypse code from the scipy book, I've made a particular adjustment wherein instead of integrating over a specific time with numpy.linspace, I want to loop over an increasing time and changing time.

But I've hit a snag, whenever I output to a dataframe file, it's always 2 element pairs that are outputted, so the loop outputs to 2 lines, when in reality I only need the final state to be recorded into a file. It's difficult to explain, but a lot easier to see once run:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.integrate import odeint
import pandas as pd

plt.ion()
plt.rcParams['figure.figsize'] = 10, 8

P = 0      # birth rate
d = 0.0001  # natural death percent (per day)
B = 0.0095  # transmission percent  (per day)
G = 0.0001  # resurect percent (per day)
A = 0.0001  # destroy percent  (per day)

# solve the system dy/dt = f(y, t)
def f(y, t):
     Si = y[0]
     Zi = y[1]
     Ri = y[2]
     # the model equations (see Munz et al. 2009)
     f0 = P - B*Si*Zi - d*Si
     f1 = B*Si*Zi + G*Ri - A*Si*Zi
     f2 = d*Si + A*Si*Zi - G*Ri
     return [f0, f1, f2]

# initial conditions
S0 = 500.             # initial population
Z0 = 30                 # initial zombie population
R0 = 60                 # initial death population
y0 = [S0, Z0, R0]     # initial condition vector

#looping over some time instead of integrating in one go.
t_a = 0 
oput = 500
t_b = t_a + oput
delta_t = t_a + 100 
tend = 1000

while t_a < tend: 
    t_c = t_a + delta_t 
    t=[t_a,t_c]
    y = odeint(f,y0,t,mxstep=10000) #Integrator
    t_a = t_c

    if(t_a > oput):
        t_b = t_b +oput

        S = y[:,0]
        R = y[:,1]
        Z = y[:,2]


        g = pd.DataFrame({'Z': Z,'R': R})
        g.to_csv('example',mode='a',sep = '\t',index=False)
```

What is the best way to go about outputting seamless data into the file rather than pairs of data?

Comment: Have you looked at the value `y` returned by `odeint`?  That is, take a look at `y.shape`.  `odeint` returns a point for each `t` value, including the starting point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, the output isn't exactly what I think you're looking for, but that is outside the scope of your question. this should fix your outputs.

```
dfs=[]
while t_a < tend: 
    t_c = t_a + delta_t 
    t=[t_a,t_c]
    y = odeint(f,y0,t,mxstep=10000) #Integrator
    t_a = t_c

    if(t_a > oput):
        t_b = t_b +oput

        S = y[:,0]
        R = y[:,1]
        Z = y[:,2]


        dfs.append(pd.DataFrame({'Z': Z,'R': R}))
#         g.to_csv('example.csv',mode='a',sep = '\t',index=False)
g=pd.concat(dfs,axis=0)
g.drop_duplicates().to_csv('example.csv',mode='a',sep = '\t',index=False)
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for the example code, that's looking a lot better. What did you mean by 'the output isn't exactly what I think you're looking for'? Any feedback you might have is greatly appreciated as it is my first time writing something like this.

Comment: it only cycles once, so the data is one row of start data then all the adjusted data is the same, its not using the new data for calc new pop values.

Comment: Oh right, I think you're right, what would I have to change for it to consider the new values and cycle over those? I just want it to keep updating until a condition is met which I will put in later

Comment: you need to set whatever your original values for pop and such to = Z and R at the end of the loop